# create table from another table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have master categories table like this

```
category_id    category_name            parent_name           parent_id
     1         animals & pet supplies       null                   0
     2         live animals            animals & pet supplies      1
     3         pet supplies            animals & pet supplies      1
     4         bird supplies           pet supplies                3
     5         clothing                     null                   0
     6         mens clothing           clothing                    5
     7         womens clothing         clothing                    5
     8         shirts                  mens clothing               6
     9         formal shirts           shirts                      8
```

when the user selects category i need to create new table with all categories and subcategories & sub sub categories (infinity subcategories). for example if user selects animals & pets supplies the new category table should be like this

```
  category_id    category_name            parent_name           parent_id
     1         animals & pet supplies       null                   0
     2         live animals            animals & pet supplies      1
     3         pet supplies            animals & pet supplies      1
     4         bird supplies           pet supplies                3
```

if the user selects clothing category then new category table should be like this

```
 category_id    category_name            parent_name           parent_id
     5         clothing                     null                   0
     6         mens clothing           clothing                    5
     7         womens clothing         clothing                    5
     8         shirts                  mens clothing               6
     9         formal shirts           shirts                      8
```

anybody please help me in achieving this. thanks in advance. suggestions to change in table designing also welcome to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create new table on selection?

Can user select any sub category directly ? 
i.e. Instead of clothing, Men's Clothing

Regards,
Maulin.